# Mass mailing using SQL Server

Tags: .net, email, html-email

Is there a way to use SQL server to send mass email? or would I have to purchase a service/API from companies like jangomail or others. what are the advantages/disadvantages to using SQL server or API services?

Comment: Yes, there is, IIRC, but why????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending a mass mailing through SQL Server is possible. Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189505.aspx.

I use this for technical notifications, warnings etc. For Mass-Mailings to customers I'd use something that allows you to make a nice looking email layout and that integrates into a CRM-System or the like.